# Complete data is not saving in the Table

Tags: product, category, catalog, data

Actually I am getting the data of the catalog_category_entity in my custom grid and delete the record. Before delete I want to save the complete data in my custom table. But only saves the three column.

This is my controller

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Category;

use Vendor\Module\Model\CategoryRuleRecordFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\CategoryRuleRecord as ResourceModel;
use Vendor\Module\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;

/**
 * Class Delete
 *
 * Delete banner action.
 */
class Delete extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface, HttpPostActionInterface
{
    protected ResourceModel $categoryResource;
    protected CategoryRuleRecordFactory $categoryRecord;
    protected CategoryFactory $categoryFactory;
    private RequestInterface $request;

    private CategoryRepository $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceModel $categoryResource,
        CategoryRuleRecordFactory $categoryRecord,
        RequestInterface $request,
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        Context $context,
        CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->categoryRecord = $categoryRecord;
        $this->categoryFactory =$categoryFactory;
        $this->categoryResource =$categoryResource;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Delete action
     *
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $model = "";
        $data = $this->request->getPostValue('entity_id');
        $categoryRecord = $this->categoryRecord->create();
        $this->categoryResource->load($categoryRecord, $data);
        {
            if ($categoryRecord->getData())
            $model = $this->categoryFactory->create();
            $model->setData($data)->save();
        }
        /** @var Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        {
            try {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                $this->categoryRepository->deleteByIdentifier($data['entity_id']);

                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('The Record has been deleted.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to save the same table data in the another table before deleting but when its saves it saves only three columns in the other tables that are entity_id, created_in, updated_in.

I want to save all columns in my table not only three.

Answer (score 0):

seems like your data have only entity_id please Try to replace
`$data = $this->request->getPostValue('entity_id');` to `$data = $this->request->getPostValue();` or `$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();`

Comment: tried but not working